# How to query Realtime Database between a certain range

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I'm implementing infinite scroll using Next.js and Firestore Realtime Database (v9.x).

When the client requests the home page, the server fetches the 4 most recent images from the database and displays them to the client. When the user reaches the bottom of the page, 4 more images should be fetched and so on.

This is my database:

[image]

Every time a user adds a new image, that image is pushed to the end of the list, just like an array/list.

For the first 4 images that are fetched in the server side and sent/displayed to the client, I'm using this code:

```js
query(ref(db, 'latest_images'), limitToLast(4))
```

This code is intended to fetch the last four images added (the most recent images).

Now, on the client side, when the user reaches the end of the page, this is the code I'm using to fetch 4 more images:

```js
query(
 ref(db, `latest_images`),
 endBefore(lastImageID), // lastImagedID = "-MqZdzr7RTYpyujV6hnP" (w/ d. quotes)
 limitToLast(4),
)
```

The `lastImageID` stores the fourth entry key from the bottom up in the database image shown above. This variable is an "anchor" so the code knows where to start querying for the 4 next images.

What I expected from the code above is that it would fetch these images (delimited by the red braces):

[image]

But it ended up fetching the same 4 images that were fetched on the server side initially (delimited by the blue braces).

From the documentarion:

> endBefore()   Return items less than the specified key or value depending on the order-by method chosen.

> limitToLast() Sets the maximum number of items to return from the end of the ordered list of results.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data?authuser=0#filtering_data

Comment: Hmmm.... at first glance your code and values look correct. 1) Can you try with `endAt` instead of `endBefore`? While `endBefore` should work and is better, it's a newer API so I want to make sure you're not hitting a bug in there. 2) Can you add `orderByKey()` to the query, just to be certain? 3) Can you export your JSON from the database and add it to your question as text, so that I can easily test with the same data?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen adding the orderByKey() did it. I created a sandbox that replicates my environment when I ran into this problem. There you will also find the JSON you requested. This is the link if you want to test: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-lucy-fndz0?file=/database.json

Comment: Hey Ricardo. Are you saying that adding `orderByKey()` fixed the problem? If so, I'll post that as answer, but might also file a documentation bug as you're not the first one to use filter operations without ordering first.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen exacly, adding `orderByKey()` fixed the problem. As soon as you post an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, you'll have to tell the database what to order on, before you can filter the data. Since you're filtering on the keys, adding `orderByKey()` to your query will ensure it knows to filter on the keys.

I've filed a bug to get this clarified in the documentation snippets, as it's quite easy to misunderstand it now.